# Sum each row of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to sum each row of a multidimensional array :

```
$number = array
(
    array(0.3,0.67, 0.3),
    array(0.3,0.5,1),
    array(0.67,0.67,0.3),
    array(1,0.3,0.5)
);
```

The result what i want is like this :

```
row1 = 1.27
row2 = 1.8
row3 = 1.64
row4 = 1.8
```

I already tried this code :

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 5; $j++) {
        $sumresult[] = array_sum($number[$i][$j]);
    }
}
```

But it appear an error like this :

> Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, double given in xxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_sum` needs array not values. Do like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $sumresult[] = array_sum($number[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been stuck on this for an hour! :)

Comment: Glad that I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

its because you are passing an value instead of the array containing it.

One correct solution would be:

```
$sumResult = array();

foreach($number as $values){
    $sumResult []= array_sum($values);
}

print_r($sumResult);
```

Should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to just map the `array_sum()` function to the array to sum the inner arrays:

```
$sumresult = array_map('array_sum', $number);
```